# Bug in ModelMultipleChoiceField? Does not handle all data types

Tags: django, modelform

Using the following code, I get the sub sequent crash.

Here is a gist of the full django app: https://gist.github.com/thnee/8e7c6b22f350582efe57

Below are the important parts:

**models.py**

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Shirt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ShirtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shirt
```

**using the form**

```
def run_form(data):
    form = ShirtForm(data)
    if form.is_valid():
        print 'success'
    else:
        print dict(form.errors)

# color id is integer (and 1 exists in database)
run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': [1,]})
# result: success

# color id is of type string
run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': ['asdf',]})
# result: {'colors': [u'"asdf" is not a valid value for a primary key.']}

# color id is of type list
run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': [['asdf'],]})
# expected result: {'colors': [u'["asdf"] is not a valid value for a primary key.']}
# actual result: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

# color id is of type dict
run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': [{'asdf': 'qwer'},]})
# expected result: {'colors': [u'{"asdf": "qwer"} is not a valid value for a primary key.']}
# actual result: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

**results in the following stack trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 194, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/code/tests/model_multiple_choice_field_check_type/mmcfct/stuff/views.py", line 26, in test
    run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': [['asdf'],]})
  File "/home/mattiasll01/code/tests/model_multiple_choice_field_check_type/mmcfct/stuff/views.py", line 12, in run_form
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 129, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 121, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 273, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 288, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1186, in clean
    self.queryset.filter(**{key: pk})
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 593, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 611, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1204, in add_q
    clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1240, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1131, in build_filter
    clause.add(constraint, AND)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/tree.py", line 104, in add
    data = self._prepare_data(data)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 79, in _prepare_data
    value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 352, in prepare
    return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 369, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/mattiasll01/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 613, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Basically what I think would be better is to not only check for `ValueError`, but also `TypeError` here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L1218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in Django ticket 22808

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22808

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything weird in the results you get since your function is waiting a string or an int, so when you're passing a dict or a list, it does not make it.

I didn't test it at all but this could give you some ideas:

```
try:
   run_form({'name': 'foo', 'colors': [['asdf'],]})
except TypeError:
   # Don't make it crash here but handle errors yourself in form.errors
```

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible to catch exceptions. However, at this point it could be a lot of different things, and it's difficult to know what the TypeError actually means. We have passed through the entire model-, form-, and db-layer. What error message do you put here? I though the whole point of the form was to validate data and return errors. How would you handle this if using generic class based views? It kind of sucks to wrap every call to is_valid?

Comment: Something I don't understand: you're passing the form data in a python dict to make your tests, but in real life, users are filling a real form with HTML inputs, aren't they? In that case, they won't be able to provide Python lists/dicts as arguments, and your problem  won't exist. (maybe I didn't understand something ^^)

Comment: Yes this is a test case, but no there is no rule in django saying that a Form can only validate request.POST. The data could be coming  from JSON through a REST API or whatever. And even if it is request.POST, users could send manipulated data manually, causing a crash.

Comment: There is no Django rule but you created a rule when you wrote `name = models.CharField(max_length=255)`: you defined that your input is supposed to be a string, not a list nor a dict. I think if you use form post data, this won't cause a crash because if a user type `['blabla']`, it won't be interpreted as a list, but as an invalid string.